# Python visualize Data

Tags: python, string

So, I coded this:

```
def visualize(records):
    data=[]
    for i in records[1]:
        data.append(list(i))
    
    print(data)

    first=0
    second=0
    third=0

    summe=0
    summe2=0
    alive_first=0
    alive_second=0
    alive_third=0

    for i in data:
        if str(i[1]) == "1":
            first += 1
        if str(i[1]) == "2":
            second += 1
        if str(i[1]) == "3":
            third += 1
        if str(i[1]) == "1" and i[0]==True:
            alive_first+=1
        if str(i[1]) == "2" and i[0]==True:
            alive_second+=1
        if str(i[1]) == "3" and i[0]==True:
            alive_third+=1
        if i[0]!=[]:
            summe2+=1
```

now, I have to visualize it like that:

```
=========== 1st Class ============
Total |**                  | 10.1%
Alive |*****               | 25.7%

=========== 2nd Class ============
Total |*******             | 32.7%
Alive |*****               | 24.1%

=========== 3rd Class ============
Total |***********         | 57.2%
Alive |****                | 19.8%
```

I actually don't even know where to start.
If anyone knows how to print the data like that, I would appreciate it! Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

> Edit: input looks like this:

```py
print(
    visualize(
        (
            ('Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Gender', 'Age', 'Fare'),
            [
                (True, 1, 'Cumings Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'female', 38, 71.2833),
                (True, 2, 'Flunky Mr Hazelnut', 'female', 18, 51.2),
                (False, 3, 'Heikkinen Miss. Laina', 'female', 26, 7.925)
            ]
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hello @Orsons! By the kind of input you showed there, my guess is that after the header, each list represents a class containing the data of each person, right? Are `total` and `alive` the only information you have to output?

Comment: Having individual variables like `first, second` etc. rather than one variable for a list or dictionary is poor design.